# Using stargazer for ridge regression results (glmnet package)

Tags: r, glmnet, stargazer

I've run a ridge regression using the following code:

```
# Download and clean data
library(ISLR)
Hitters.data  <- Hitters
Hitters.data <- na.omit(Hitters.data)
Hitters.data$League <- as.numeric(Hitters.data$League == "A")
Hitters.data$Division <- as.numeric(Hitters.data$Division == "E")
Hitters.data$ NewLeague <- as.numeric(Hitters.data$ NewLeague == "A")

# Run ridge regression
library(glmnet)
x <-as.matrix(Hitters.data[,-which(colnames(Hitters.data)=="HmRun")])
y <- Hitters.data$HmRun
ridge.model.best = glmnet(x,y,alpha=0,lambda=0.814517)
```

I want to print the regression results using the stargazer package, but I'm not sure how.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801130/extracting-coefficient-variable-names-from-glmnet-into-a-data-frame