# How to extract multiple levels of coefficients into data frame in R?

Tags: r, glmnet, coefficients

I extracted the coefficients from my glmnet model with code:

```
best_lambda_fit_coef <- coef(best_lambda_fit)
```

I got a list of coefficients that are in dgCMatrix, but I'm not sure how to make it a data frame. I looked the answer from Mehrad in  [Extracting coefficient variable names from glmnet into a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801130/extracting-coefficient-variable-names-from-glmnet-into-a-data-frame), but it doesn't work for my situation. Below is the screenshot of the extracted dgCMatrix. Please advise. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

data.frame(matrix(unlist(best_lambda_fit_coef), nrow=251, byrow=T))

Comment: Can you please add more details on how this solves the issue?