# Change coefficient of cv.glmnet fitted regression in R

Tags: r, glmnet

I know how to "extract" coefficient from cv.glmnet. But is there a way to change the coefficient of a fitted object? I know it's kind of a hack, but I want to manually tweak the coefficients of a fitted object just for my own experiment.

[Extracting coefficient variable names from glmnet into a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801130/extracting-coefficient-variable-names-from-glmnet-into-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coefficients for glmnet are stored under `$glmnet.fit$beta` :

```
library(glmnet)
library(Matrix)

fit = cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(mtcars[,-1]),y=mtcars[,1])

head(fit$glmnet.fit$beta)
6 x 79 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 79 column names ‘s0’, ‘s1’, ‘s2’ ... ]]
                                                                        
cyl  . -0.01192151 -0.1447790 -0.2658654 -0.376195 -0.4770942 -0.5686616
disp .  .           .          .          .         .          .        
hp   .  .           .          .          .         .          .        
drat .  .           .          .          .         .          .        
wt   . -0.45776130 -0.7006176 -0.9218541 -1.123436 -1.3065806 -1.4739808
qsec .  .           .          .          .         .          .
```

It's one column for every lambda tested and when you call `coefficients()`, by default you pull out the column corresponding to `fit$lambda.1se`. Let's say we want to change that column:

```
coefficients(fit,s=fit$lambda.1se)

11 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       1
(Intercept) 33.940487806
cyl         -0.843038418
disp         .          
hp          -0.006965929
drat         .          
wt          -2.365917424
qsec         .          
vs           .          
am           .          
gear         .          
carb         .       

wh = which(fit$lambda==fit$lambda.1se)
fit$glmnet.fit$beta[,wh] = runif(nrow(fit$glmnet.fit$beta))

coefficients(fit,s=fit$lambda.1se)

11 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                      1
(Intercept) 33.94048781
cyl          0.45636267
disp         0.28286532
hp           0.04186184
drat         0.55084730
wt           0.35273817
qsec         0.96165338
vs           0.79227125
am           0.01036681
gear         0.47738589
carb         0.17170791
```

And other columns and the intercept remains unchanged:

```
11 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                      1
(Intercept) 36.38102033
cyl         -0.87610600
disp         .         
hp          -0.01377978
drat         .         
wt          -2.75934250
qsec         .         
vs           .         
am           0.16806977
gear         .         
carb        -0.01384960
```

It is really weird to do it. If you want to change the coefficients for prediction purposes, you can always pull out coefficients, alter and multiply them with your data matrix again.